# Filter from a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to filter data in flutter. But, when I filter the data, the length of list is zero. I want to filter based on multiple selection by user.
Here's my code:

List status = [
'Mon',
'Tue',
'Wed',
'Thu',
'Fri',
];

```
Content(
          title: 'Filter Days',
          child: FormField<List<String>>(
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            autovalidate: true,
            initialValue: appsTags,
            builder: (state) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: ChipsChoice<String>.multiple(
                      value: state.value,
                      options: ChipsChoiceOption.listFrom<String,
                          String>(
                        source: status,
                        value: (i, v) => v,
                        label: (i, v) => v,
                      ),
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        state.didChange(val);
                        if (this.mounted) {
                          setState(() {
                            list = apps
                                .where((i) => i['status'] == val
                            ).toList();
                          });
                        }
                        print(list.length);
                      },
                      itemConfig: ChipsChoiceItemConfig(
                        selectedColor: AppColors.primaryAccentColor,
                        selectedBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                        unselectedColor:
                        AppColors.primaryAccentColor,
                        unselectedBorderOpacity: .3,
                      ),
                      isWrapped: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Hi There. Instead of posting full code, add only a minimum reproducible sample that contains your original list, how you are filtering and what its output is and what you were expecting.

Comment: @NisanthReddy OK, I'll change

Comment: I believe you're referring to the line `list = apps.where(...)`. What is the content of `apps`?

Comment: Yes right @Gpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the onChanged() method content:

```
                             setState(() {
                                list = apps
                                    .where((i) =>
                                    val.contains(i['status'])
                                ).toList();
                              });
```